# How to install VLC Player offline?

Tags: software-installation, permissions

my hard drive is kaput and don't want to order a new one yet so I'm running Ubuntu from usb stick every morning. I need VLC Player to watch live stream videos and don't want to install it everyday so I wanted to download the package and install it offline but I can't get past this "permission denied" error when I try to run the command './configure'. I tried to move the files to home directory and run 'chmod +x configure' command but they didn't work. Please help.

I have to add that installing VLC Player on Ubuntu Software takes ages and I can't even see the installation status.

Comment: Is the USB a persistent live media? If not you can not install VLC on it. Or any software for that matter.

Comment: No, it is a flash disk. So, I wanted to copy the files to the hard drive (it is kaput but I can stil copy files to it) but I receive this error saying "folder cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination". It seems I cannot do many things on my own computer.

Comment: I have to say you are wasting your time the drive needs to be replaced there is no point to this.

Comment: install from deb file?  (you will have to find it)

Comment: No. I downloaded tarball file from videolan's website. It is the source code. Can't I install from it?